# WordPress resuming an order from My Account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been looking for a while but haven't found the answer. Can someone tell me if there is a WordPress/Woocommerce hook we can use when someone is paying for an order from My Account page. An order can be created but then perhaps payment fails or the customer cancels the transaction. If they go to their My Account page they can pay for the order & resume it. I need to do a check here & throw an error if a condition is not met before they make payment. So between clicking "Pay for order" & actually paying for the order.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem. There are many types by which you can get this, but for you, you can use order status. First of all, check order status which is not completed, then pull that order and set status pending again. You can do it with the code and with admin panel, for your help.

```
function mysite_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order_id ) {
    error_log( "Order complete for order $order_id", 0 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'mysite_woocommerce_order_status_completed', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hi, I need to run a check before order is completed. Before processing payment.